# How to delete the first row in the .csv file

Tags: vbscript

I need to delete the first row of the CSV file.

In my script I received CSV file as argument and it's first row contains some unwanted data.
So I need to remove the first row only before processing it.

Comment: don't know much about vbscript, but usually you read the first line and then start your while loop to handle the rest of the file (without deleting anything)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set csv = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(...))

If Not csv.AtEndOfStream Then csv.SkipLine  'skip first row

Do Until csv.AtEndOfStream
  line = csv.ReadLine
  'process read line
Loop

csv.Close
```

Of course you could just as well do a `ReadLine` without processing the returned value for skipping the first line, as [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189135/1630171) suggested, but IMO `SkipLine` better reflects the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Do a .ReadLine immediately after opening the input file. This will restrict a later line loop -

```
Do Until .AtEndOfStream
   .ReadLine
   ... process ...
Loop
```

or a .ReadAll() to the data from the second line onwards only.