# equivalent sed command for deleting rows in CSV file

Tags: csv, vbscript, sed

Apreciate any help and excuse me if my terminology is incorrect.

```
find ./ -iname '*.csv' -exec sed -i '1,6d;$ d' '{}' ';'
```

This unix command, run on cygwin, will go through all the files in the directory and subdirectories that end with .csv 
For each file it deletes the 1st 6 rows and the last row and that's the returned file.

**My question is how do i write the equivalent in a vbs script?**

I tried to edit something like this([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188721/how-to-delete-the-first-row-in-the-csv-file-using-vbscript)) to fit my requirements but no joy.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set csv = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(...))

If Not csv.AtEndOfStream Then csv.SkipLine  'skip first row

Do Until csv.AtEndOfStream
  line = csv.ReadLine
  'process read line
Loop

csv.Close
```

Note: I would then like to schedule this vbs script periodically using task scheduler

EDIT
the file would look as follows before running the script: (the number of rows between row7 and row?? is variable and unknown)

```
<blank line/row1>
<blank line/row2>
<Text would be on this row/line3>
<Text would be on this row/line4>
<Text would be on this row/line5>
<blank line/row6>
<Text would be on this row/line7>
.
.
.
<Text would be on this row/line??>
<Text would be on this Last row/line>
```

Comment: +1 for attempting to solve your problem. But ... the operating model for text processing between sed and vbs has very few common points. Consider editing your question to include example data further examples of showing what transformations occur in that text from each `sed` command. Some `vbs` programmers may understand the `sed` command, but many more will understand and example that says I have this data X, and I need to transform it to Y. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim fso, csv, Iter, ThisLine

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set csv = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(...))

Iter=1
while not csv.AtEndOfStream 
   ' Buffer the line for last line test
   ThisLine = csv.ReadLine

   ' stdout if after the 6th line and not the last (the one EOF is true after reading the line)
   if (Iter > 6) and ( not csv.AtEndOfStream) then
      wscript.echo ThisLine
    end if
   Iter = Iter + 1
 wend

csv.Close
```

if the constraint is X last line instead of last one, you should first read the file, count the line than back with the evaluation of line number with this object (stream text file).
Otherwise, if not too big, load in memory a buffer of X line or use another method to read the file (ADO by example where you have a notion of cursor to know the absolute place of the line and last line number)

Comment: tks that looks like a starting point. I just need to work out how to write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\path\to\your.csv"

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filename & ".tmp", 2, True)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  If inFile.Line <= 6 Then
    inFile.SkipLine
  Else
    if Not IsEmpty(line) Then outFile.WriteLine line
    line = inFile.ReadLine
  End If
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close

fso.DeleteFile filename, True
fso.MoveFile filename & ".tmp", filename
```

The trick here is that you print the line from the previous iteration before reading the current line. That way the last line is omitted.