# How to read a specific line data

Tags: vbscript

I want to read a specific line from the text file using VBScript.

I have explored Read and ReadLine methods but I can't able to read only specific line from text file. (I have 1000 of line but I want to read only 99 or 200 or 500 line only)

Comment: @KobyDouek this question is about VBScript not VB or VB.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **question** may be similar to the questions those duplicate hunters pointed to, but the **answers** are - for different reasons - of no use. A **good answer** could be build from one answer to the completely **different** question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18188721/603855).

Now to the answer:

Use a [.SkipLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/092z1463(v=vs.84).aspx) loop to read to the line before you are interested in and get it using .ReadLine.

Comment: People can ask the same roundabout question in numerous ways which aren't excuses to produce duplicates all over the place for the same exact methods. I agree that `SkipLine()` is the better method to use in this case.

Comment: I don't understand you?? You basically have found the correct duplicate target but you post a derogatory answer instead of pointing to the correct answer, you have the privileges...use them!